# Problem creating a new data Type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a new data type in Haskell that has basically the same elements has the Int type with some more. I made it like this:

```
data Novo = -2147483648|-2147483647|...|-1|0|1|2|...|2147483647|(|+|)|(|*|) deriving (Show)
```

I know this is pseudocode but how do i write it then?

And when I try to compilate this the gchi gives me this error:

```
parse error on input ‘-’
```

refering to the 13 character in this line which is the first `-` can you help me here? Why is it giving me this error? How do i solve this?

Comment: I searched 4 it and what i found i didn't understand so yeah

Comment: You'll find in the book that you appear to have taken this example from, that this is pseudocode and not in the least valid Haskell.

Comment: How do i make a function that is like (|+|) x y = (i don't know what to write in here, what do i put here?) which type is Novo -> Novo -> Novo

Comment: @RuiFernando SO isn't a mentoring service. Not that there's anything wrong with asking for mentoring or beginner's help, but it really doesn't fit well with the format of SO and if you read through [ask] and the rest of the [help] I think they explain pretty clearly why that's the case. Try [a forum or chat](https://www.haskell.org/community) instead perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

A data constructor must be either a valid identifier starting with a capital letter, or a sequence of symbols starting with a `:` .

Your attempt has the following problems:

1. Numeric literals like `-2147483648` are not valid constructors.
2. You cannot specify a range of constructors with `...`. An example like `data Fourbit = -16 | ... | -1 | 0 | 1 | ... 15`, is  pseudocode for an explicit listing of every intended literal:

   ```
   data Fourbit = -16 | -15 | -14 | -13 | -12 | -11 | -10 | -9 |
                   -8 | -7 | -6 | -5 | -4 | -3 | -2 | -1 |
                    0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
                    8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15
   ```

   which is *also* pseudocode, because the literals are not valid data constructors.
3. Your strings `(|+|)` and `(|*|)` are *also* invalid names for data constructors. They don't begin with a `:`, and they contain parentheses.

If you *really* wanted to pursue this route, you need to be prepared to list ~4 billion constructors, using names like `NovoNeg2147483648`, `Novo2147483648`, `NovoPlus`, and `NovoMult`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor names must start with a capital letter or `:`. Digits or other symbols are not allowed. Some numeric predefined types like `Int` behave "as if" they were defined as you show above, but that's pseudo-syntax, not actual valid Haskell.

Try instead some variant of

```
data Novo = PlainInt Int | Additional1 | Additional2 deriving Show
```

Comment: I'm not understanding can you explain better?

Comment: @RuiFernando Perhaps chepner's answer below is more detailed (please also read that). Is there any specific part of our answers where you need more explanation?

Comment: I'm not really getting it at all so the how do u specify that `NovoMult` is my `|*|`? and how do i specify all the numbers like let's make it from 20 to 20?

Comment: @RuiFernando You can't use `|*|` as a name, you need to use something like `Mult` or some infix symbol starting with `:` like `:*:` (but only if you also have two arguments to such constructor). There is no way to specify "a number from -20 to 20" in types. You could add 41 constructors like `M20 | M19 | ... | Z | P1 | P2 | ... | P20` explicitly writing all of them (without the ellipsis), but that's inconvenient.

Comment: @RuiFernando The type that I defined above has all the values `Int` has (wrapped in the `PlainInt` constructor), plus two more values (named `Additional1`, `Additional2`). Isn't that what you wanted, except for the naming?

Comment: Yeah that's what i wanted but then how do i put that Additional1 corresponds to |+|?

Comment: @RuiFernando |+| is only a name, you can call it differently, but let it represent the same thing. You could use `data Novo = PlainInt Int | Plus | Times`, if you want better names.

Comment: and now how do i make a function that is like  `(|+|)  x y = (i don't know what to write in here, what do i put here?)` which type is `Novo  -> Novo -> Novo`

Comment: If `|+|` is intended to be a data constructor, there's nothing more to do, just like `(:) x []` doesn't simplify to any other list (and `[x]` is just syntactic sugar, not a "simpler" value).

Comment: @RuiFernando I now have lost you. First you wanted some extra elements. Then you wanted to constrain integers. Now the extra elements are actually a function. This is very confusing. I can't understand what you want -- maybe you also don't understand what you really want. Anyway, I think I can't answer this question properly because it is too vague. :-/